# GMSPlace error with Expected a Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, google-places

I am using [MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField](https://github.com/TheMrugraj/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField) I am getting the above error when I implemented it at my Code. I don't even know where to debug. I have followed exactly the same implementation with the sample.

[image: 123]

[image: 456]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After installing the latest [pod.](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start#step-3-install-the-api-using-cocoapods)
2. Drag `MVPlaceSearchTextField` into your project folder
3. Add `#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>` at all significant areas
4. Put this code with your key

`[GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBJvZbCA-BiAE3HBgddxm6TTjAiVkYTU9Kk"];`

at `AppDelegates.m`

5. Put the key at your VC

   `_txtPlaceSearch.strApiKey= @"AIzaSyBJvZbCABiAE3HBgddxm6TTjAiVkYTU9Kk";`

it should work.